# Deploying a sharepoint solution

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, deployment

I'm new to sharepoint site development. I've developed a sharepoint 2013 site and would like to view in user's mode. Currently it is in designer mode with edit options. But, I would like to view in end user mode so that I can know how it appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to save what you have done so far and then checkout from the webpage. After that u can log-gin as different user and view what you have done.

Comment: I mean can I access the content through public URL within the intranet.